# How to use parameters for a report to refresh at runtime

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am calculating the score and weight of a result based on a target result and conditions for two measures. These is the dataset I have

```
GroupName       Measure1   Measure2
Group1           0.8        0.7
Group2           0.4        0.8
```

Currently I am calculating the Score & Weight using two different if functions, like

```
Measure1 Weight Score = 
var kk=IF(
    'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] > 0.85,
    "5",
    IF(
        'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] < 0.85 && 'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] >0.7,
        "3",
        If('Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] < 0.7,"1"
    )))
    Return kk *0.5
```

What I am want is when a user use the report and asked to input the parameter for GroupName then the Score and Weight should change automatically by the value set for each GroupName and calculate the result? any help apperciated.

Comment: let me know If my answer remains the solution that you use, feel free to accept it. Else please share your answer so future readers and I will know how you solved your problem. ✌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters here. Refer: [Create or edit a report parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-parameters#create-or-edit-a-report-parameter)

In top header ribbon, choose Modeling and click on “What If” parameter

create a new parameter, what-if parameter [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5CSY.png) to set the type and range of value that users can input. This will add a slicer to the page where user can choose.

Create a measure to interact with your report. You can add in your calculation for the result to be with your existing data and the user input(add parameter reference in your weight calculation measure).

Simple Example to multiply the source data with the input value from user:

```
Measure = [Parameter Value]*CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Value]))
```

you can also create a measure to view the parameter selected using as below

```
Parameter Value = SELECTEDVALUE(Parameter[Parameter])
```

Comment: That is a very good information, thanks. Currently I have 4 measures that are scored and weighthed using the above logic but with different score and weight. If I want to do the parameters, Do I have to create multiple parameters like for example for measure1..I have added the parameters as an example BELOW. Do I have to create 8 parameters for measure1? and that means for 4 measures it will be 32 parameters.

Comment: Measure1 Weight Score = 
var kk=IF(
    'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] > PARAM1,
    "PARAM2",
    IF(
        'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] < PARAM3 && 'Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] >PARAM4,
        "PARAM5",
        If('Sprints'[Velocity%_NEW] < PARAM6,"PARAM7"
    )))
    Return kk *PARAM8

Comment: yes if you have different value for each then you would have to use different parameters. please mark the answer if it was of some help.

Comment: You can reuse the same parameter in multiple measures if that is in line with your required logic.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh at run time. for example ask the user the Group Name he want to select and when selected then pass the score and weight to the above query and refresh the whole report?

Comment: [Automatic page refresh in the Power BI service][5] to set automatic page refresh for reports as long as the data source is DirectQuery.

Power BI Desktop has no restrictions for refresh intervals and can be as frequent as every second. But when reports are published to the Power BI service, certain restrictions apply    [5]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh#automatic-page-refresh-in-the-power-bi-service

Comment: The end user cannot refresh the data in a report manually without permissions. You can either set up a refresh schedule or else build your report using a DirectQuery which will always use the current data. There is no other input interaction I am aware of. You can try power automate to design a flow to query based on used input, update a dataset and this report can direct query from there. Of course this would require a input interface apart from published report (form etc).